# How to shuffle items in list, whilst avoiding any item remaining in the original position?

Tags: python, random

I have an issue with `random.shuffle`. Basically, it works just fine in order to pseudo randomize items in list, but in my case I also want to prevent an item from remaining in the same position.

I've came up with this code in order to ensure that every item gets a new position.

```
match = True
while match is True:
    for i in range(len(initial_list)):
        if initial_list[i]==result_list[i]:
            random.shuffle(result_list)
            match = True
        else:
            match = False
```

This code passes tests (if shuffle can be done), but is there an easier & faster way to do it?

Comment: Note that, although `random.shuffle` does use PRNG, an algorithm that ensures that each element ends up in a different place is _less_ random than that.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Indeed, something that looks or sounds more random [may be less random](http://muller.lbl.gov/teaching/Physics10/old%20physics%2010/chapters%20(old)/4-Randomness.htm)

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes, I understand issue of being it less random, but my intention is to do something that perfectly shuffles items, not just to randomize position (here comes initial problem), so if something is less random, but more effective - works just fine.

Comment: You need to explain what you think "perfectly shuffle" means.  Simply shifting each item one position back in the list (and wrapping the last one back to the beginning) gives each item a new position, but few would consider that a "perfect shuffle".

Comment: @BrenBarn yes, indeed, I consider that as my fault. However, as it goes more about value, in situation where `list = [1, 1, 2, 3]` shifting will just fail, as `list[0]` will still be 1. So this is why I still need some so to say controlled random. But again, yes, should be more accurate in words next time.

Comment: @ntrme: The answer you accepted also won't ensure that.

Comment: @BrenBarn agreed. Can you also give me advice whether to update post with explanation which I gave here or it is not welcomed?

Comment: Note now that, given the additional restriction that datasets may have duplicate elements and yet must still put _equal_ elements in all new positions, some datasets cannot be shuffled in this manner, e.g. `[1, 1, 2]`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 indeed, this is a problem, and I didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: There is no solution to that. It is mathematically impossible.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I mean not to a problem of shuffling items that cannot be shuffled, but to terminating while loop after certain time (or maybe some algorithm to check whether shuffling is possible at all).

Comment: If the most common element constitutes more than half of the list, the list cannot be shuffled in that manner.

Answer (score 7):

The [actual implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b29ce8ec2cdcf034977799e65dca1f3342b409fc/Lib/random.py#L260) of `random.shuffle` is quite simple:

```
for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
    # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
    j = int(random() * (i+1))
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

With a slight modification of the same idea, we can add in your new  requirement:

```
from random import random

def my_shuffle(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        raise Exception
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = int(random() * i)
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

it would work:

```
import random
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

def shuffle(x):
    freePlaces = [i for i in range(len(x))]
    def rec(firstPlace,freePlaces):
        secondPlace = int(random.choices(freePlaces)[-1])
        if firstPlace != secondPlace:
            freePlaces.remove(secondPlace)
            return secondPlace
        return rec(firstPlace,freePlaces)
    return [x[rec(firstPlace,freePlaces)] for firstPlace in freePlaces.copy()]
            
print(a)
a =shuffle(a)
print(a)
```

you can also do:

```
     import random
     l1 = [1,2,3,4,5] ;l2 = l1.copy()
     print(l1)
     while l1 ==l2:
         random.shuffle(l1)
     print(l1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was what I used when I had this question:

```
import random

list_one = ["Dave", "Bob", "Stan", "Reginald", "Barry"]
list_length = len(list_one)
list_two = [""] * list_length

indices_remaining = []
for i in range(0, list_length):
    indices_remaining.append(i)

for i in range(list_length):
    choosing = True
    while choosing:
        r_index = random.randrange(0, len(indices_remaining))
        if indices_remaining[r_index] != i:
            list_two[indices_remaining[r_index]] = list_one[i]
            del indices_remaining[r_index]
            choosing = False
print(list_two)
```

The output was:

```
["Reginald", "Stan", "Barry", "Dave", "Bob"]
```